# C++ Drawing a contiguos texturized quads using triangle_strip

Tags: c++, opengl, textures

This is a font renderer derived from [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/oglbmfont/). I have mostly changed its code to the way it would be much faster (as I see it is). Now I came to the point that I see that

> **glCallList()** < **glDrawArrays()** < **glDrawElements(GL_QUADS)** < **glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP)**...so it means that **glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP)** is the most efficient way in this kind of rendering.

However, after switching from `GL_QUADS` to `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP`, the texture became like this:

(Note that I swap the last 4 values of vertices and texture coordinates when switching from `GL_QUADS` to `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP`)

[image: such nonsense description]

and esp. the code:

```
void Text2D::PrintText5( BMfont& font, int x, int y, const char* text) {

float w = 0;
glPushAttrib(GL_LIST_BIT | GL_CURRENT_BIT  | GL_ENABLE_BIT | GL_TRANSFORM_BIT);

glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
//glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, font.mmat);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

glScalef(font.scale, font.scale, 1.f);

if (!compiledd)
while (*text)
{
    compiledd = true;
    const BMchar& _char(font.chars[(int)*(text++)]);
    if (_char.width) {

        const float verices[] = {
            (float) x + w + _char.x_ofs              , (float) y + _char.height + _char.y_ofs,
            (float) x + w + _char.width + _char.x_ofs, (float) y + _char.height + _char.y_ofs,

            (float) x + w + _char.x_ofs              , (float) y + _char.y_ofs,
            (float) x + w + _char.width + _char.x_ofs, (float) y + _char.y_ofs,
        };

        for (int i = 0;i < sizeof(verices) / sizeof(float); ++i) {
            verts3.push_back(verices[i]);
        }

        const float texcoords[] = {
            (float) _char.x / (float) font.scaleW               , (float) InvertY2((_char.y + _char.height) / (float) font.scaleH),
            (float)(_char.x + _char.width) / (float) font.scaleW, (float) InvertY2((_char.y + _char.height) / (float) font.scaleH),

            (float) _char.x / (float) font.scaleW               , (float) InvertY2( _char.y / (float) font.scaleH),
            (float)(_char.x + _char.width) / (float) font.scaleW, (float) InvertY2( _char.y / (float) font.scaleH),
        };

        for (int i = 0;i < sizeof(texcoords) / sizeof(float); ++i) {
            coords3.push_back(texcoords[i]);
        }

        const unsigned char colors[] = {
            255, 0, 255,
            255, 0, 255,
            255, 0, 255,
            255, 0, 255
        };

        indices3.push_back(a++);indices3.push_back(a++);indices3.push_back(a++);indices3.push_back(a++);

        for (int i = 0;i < sizeof(colors) / sizeof(unsigned char); ++i) {
            color3.push_back(colors[i]);
        }

        w += (float)(_char.x_advance - _char.x_ofs);

    } else w += (float)font.base;

}

glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_INDEX_ARRAY);

glVertexPointer  (2, GL_FLOAT, 0, &verts3[0]);
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, &coords3[0]);
glColorPointer(3, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0, &color3[0]);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, font.texture);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, verts3.size() / 2, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, &indices3[0]);

glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_INDEX_ARRAY);

glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glPopAttrib();
}
```

**how can I do the last font renderer to render same as other?**

(it's still working even I don't have `glIndexPointer()` ???)

Comment: Two things: quads are not in the same order as a triangle strip. And secondly, *text should not be contiguous*. Not unless you hate kerning and proper text layout.

Comment: so does it mean its impossible to do this?

Comment: If you're asking if it's impossible to use the same index data for quads and triangle strips, the answer is yes. Also, "index arrays" are not what you think they are.

Comment: I'm not really sure but, I know it as *the order in which each vertex will be drawn?*. If you have any suggestions on how can I achieve this, please post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**And Yep, I figured it out again..guess what? Its impossible to do this**

Comment: It would be interesting to know if there is a more costly way to still get this to render, but not to use `glDrawElements` maybe?